# Why doesnt string.equals("astring") work?

Tags: java

Why don't I get 20 after delivering e.g. "Obsidian" to `Test(String pStr)` if I call `getMatInt()` ?

Also tried .`toString()` after all String-declariations, also declarated e.g. "Obsidian" as `new String` a. Nothing works.

getBonus is aways returning a 0 instead of a 20/30/... . 
I already tried "Obsidian" and "obsidian", both doesnt work for me ...

```
public class test
{
  private String str;
  private int matInt;
  private int bonus;
  private int magic;

 public test(int pMagic, String pStr)
{
      int magic = pMagic;
      str = pStr;
 }

 private void materialEquals()
 {

     if(str.equals("Obsidian"))
     {
         matInt = 20;
     }
     .....
 }

 private void calcBonus()
 {
     materialEquals();
     bonus = magic * matInt;
 }

 public int getBonus()
 {
     calcBonus();
     return bonus;
 }

}
```

Comment: Because you never call `materialEquals`, at least in this code.

Comment: Forgot to add it, it still doesnt work

Comment: assuming it still doesn't work after your edit, in what context are you calling `getMatInt()`? Can we see your main method or the code block you call it in?

Comment: Take the time to put together a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) - as is, there is no way we can help you, because the code you've provided is incomplete.  If you put together a short example of the behavior you're seeing that we can run, we can explain why.  As an added bonus, just putting together an SSCCE is a great debugging tool, and often helps uncover your bug yourself.

Comment: There is something you are not showing that is causing it not to work. since the code at is stands (assuming you call `materialEquals()` )  should return 20 when you call  `getMatInt()` and it does when compiled here.

Comment: Okay, I extended the code. I want to calculate an int bonus = magic * matInt (an material has specific values)

Comment: This looks like it should work.  Are you perhaps entering "obsidian" (note lower case)?  What context are you calling these methods in and what errors are you getting?

Comment: getBonus is aways returning a 0 instead of a 20/30/... . I already tried "Obsidian" and "obsidian", both doesnt work for me ... This class is used in a game for a weapon, a weapon can consist of different materials. Its strength is dependend on the materials and its magic.

Comment: see edits to my answer, also use `str.equalsIgnoreCase()` in your `materialsEquals()` method to make it more flexible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
public int getMatInt()
{
     materialEquals();
     return matInt;
}
```

There is no reason for this in your constructor: `str = new String(pStr);`, just use `str = pStr`.

In fact, you might be better off setting `matInt` in your constructor:

```
public test(String pStr)
{
     str = pStr;
     materialEquals();
}
```

And depending on how many materials you have, you might want to look into using enumeration.

Ok after your edits:

```
 public int getBonus()
{
 calcBonus(); //bonus won't be calculated otherwise
 return bonus;
}
```

After further edits:

Your constructor is wrong, you're not initializing `int magic`.  Try this constructor instead.

```
public test(int pMagic, String pStr)
{
  this.magic = pMagic; //int magic = pMagic was a new variable only in the constructor scope
  this.str = pStr;
  calcBonus();
 }
```

Also you might as well calculate the bonus on construction.

Comment: I forgot to add the method again, sorry. Updated my code, it still doesnt work for me.

Comment: That works, thanks. I wasn't getting a NPE bizarrely.

Comment: actually that make senses, an int can't be null, it defaults to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call `materialEquals()` so that `20` can be assigned to `matInt` upon `equals` comparison, as integers are always initialized to default value `0` upon declaration.